# reactjs flux send data from child component to parent

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm running into a "doing it the right way" dilemma and could use some expertise.  I have a parent component:

```
<Articles>
```

and inside of that component, I'm rendering a child component for each article:

```
<Article>
```

When an `Article` is clicked, I want to send an `articleId` to the parent `<Articles>` component.  The `<Articles>` component is going to then dispatch whatever it needs to back to my `ArticleStore` to handle the data and emit *back* to my `<Articles>` component.

My question is, is it ok to pass my `articleId` directly to the parent, or since i'm using the Flux architecture, should I dispatch the `articleId` to the store, and then let the store emit the `articleId` back to the parent?

Comment: I am no professional. But i think it depend on the property of that data. If that data will change rapidly and will not used in other component. Just passing it to parent component directly is a acceptable solution.

Comment: yeah I think you're right, also, since there is no data actually changing, the state of the app will not change so there really isnt a need to notify the store.  I think the way I have it now is the right way.  Thanks for your response @KitFung

Answer (score 1):

To keep concerns separated the `Article` component should have no direct knowledge of it's parent. So the only way it should communicate back to the parent `Articles` is by way of a callback passed from `Articles` (e.g. `articleIdChangeHandler`). Then the callback can do whatever you want including setting `articleId`as state in `Articles` or dispatching `articleId` to the store.

Generally you don't want to expose Flux actions in lower level components, so you probably don't want to directly dispatch from `Article`.

Whether to keep the single source of truth of `articleId` as state in `Articles` or in the Flux store is always an interesting question. More often than not I find that things like `articleId` need a more global scope than I initially thought, so it may start out as component state, but often ends up in the store after all.